# Configuring Spring Boot application.yml with Environment Variables from .env File

Tags: spring-boot, docker, yaml, environment-variables, github-actions

I want to retrieve values from the .env file when running the Spring Boot application and pass them to application-dev. I have tried multiple times but couldn't succeed.

The main goal is to keep environment variables in a GitHub Action as a base64-encoded string and convert them to .env when building the image. As the initial step, I want to achieve this.

```
# application.yml
spring:
  profiles:
    active: dev

# application-dev.yml
server:
  port: '8008'
spring:
  datasource:
    url: 'jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb'
    username: ${SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME}
    password: ${SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD}
    driver-class-name: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver

# .env
SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME=admin
SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD=admin
```

I created a base64 string and used it to create a .env file locally.

Method 1:
Started the application.

Method 2:
In the Dockerfile, added a step as follows:

```
COPY .env /opt/app/.env
```

After that, I built the Docker image and ran the image. However, I encountered an issue where the .env values were not reflected in the application.yml file.

Comment: Isn't a `.env` file only for `docker compose`? Adding a `.env` file to the container won't do anything afaik. You can just provide them with `-e` when starting the container (or create a `compose.yml` so it can be used). Tip when passing `SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME` you don't need to explicitl define it in your `application.yml` that will automatically be picked up by Spring Boot.